# URL SEO /id/slug VS. /slug-id

Tags: url, seo, slug, unique-id

In short, I was wondering about which is best for good SEO?

```
https://example.com/articles/{id}/{slug}
https://example.com/articles/18/new-atlas-robot-revealed
```

or

```
https://example.com/articles/{slug}-{id}
https://example.com/articles/new-atlas-robot-revealed-18
```

Or, does it matter for SEO?

Is it related to Google News?

The first one is used by StackOverflow and it does a redirect when a slug did not given (or wrong) to the right, slugged version. And I'm liking it.

But while I'm surfing on the internet, I mostly see URLs like the second one.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **SEO** which is off-topic at Stack Overflow. Please read ["Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382618) to better understand when SEO questions are acceptable to ask here (most are not) and where you might be able to get assistance.

Comment: Apparently, [Google now ignores keywords in the URL](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/47348/94338), so it shouldn't matter which one you choose. However, from a user standpoint, I think the `/{id}/` version is more readable. That's the approach taken by Stack Overflow, for example.

Answer (score 3):

Actually for the url naming, you can understanding as this way:

`/` directory, or you can say folder path etc. For example: *home/product/producta*

`-` spacing replacement, For example: *home/product/stack-overflow-product-a*

Take an example your question url on Stack Overflow here:
`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60635996/url-seo-id-slug-vs-slug-id`

I am sure you see the sample :D
Here is more information for your references:
https://moz.com/learn/seo/url

https://yoast.com/seo-friendly-urls/

https://yoast.com/wordpress-seo-url-permalink/

Hope it helps!